# Export 3 SQL Query results to 3 sheets in an excel sheet through python pandas

Tags: python, sql, excel, pandas

How to make the code work more intelligently & export results of 3 different queries to 3 different sheets of a single .xls file ?

Answer (score 0):

save your queries results in individual 3 dataframes. and then it looks like this-
pandas is alias here as pd.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filename.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    yours1stdataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='whatverulike')
     yours2nddataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='whatverulike')
     yours3rddataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='whatverulike')

    writer.save()
```

This should solve your problem.